# In System.Out.println() what's the point of synchronizing this block?

Tags: java

From the `PrintStream.class`:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

1. What's the point of the `synchronized(this)`?
2. Isn't it the same to do `public synchronized void println(Object x){...}` and removing the `synchronized(this)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`synchronized` prevents multiple threads from entering the method or block at the same time. `print` and `println` aren't thread safe methods, meaning if you have two threads call them at the same time, the output may get mixed.

e.g. thread 1 calls `print('Hello World')` right when thread 2 calls `print('Goodbye World')`. The output may look like `HeGoodbyello W Woorldrld`

The reason for using `synchronized(this)` here instead of putting `synchronized` on the method is because `String.valueOf(x)` does not need to block other threads, and is therefore placed outside the critical section.

Generally, you want to put as little as possible into the critical section to prevent threads from waiting around wasting time.

Answer (score 2):

1.: To avoid that multiple threads write in the same line, resulting in a mix of both lines. (At least the line and the following newLine() could be out of order)

2: nearly, when removing the `synchronized(this)` the whole method is blocked so including the `valueOf()`, the original code blocks only where neccessary.

Generally synchronisation is needed when accessing shared resources. In the example this is the console. the String s is not shared accros multiple threads, so a sync is not neccesssary.

Answer (score 2):

- The point of the synchronization is that when you call `println`, you expect your data to be printed with a newline at its end. So it wouldn't do if another thread using the same `PrintStream` suddenly comes in the middle and prints its own data before your newline is printed.
- The difference between that and synchronizing the entire method is that there is no point in not allowing different threads to convert their data to string in parallel. Each thread can convert its value without contesting for the common resource (the stream), and only then they go into the critical section.